# Bootstrap card with fixed width in a column (responsive)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I have a `Bootstrap-card` but there is a problem with its `width`. I'd like to that card will take a full with of the column which I set. Here is a piece of code that I use and screenshot which presents actual width and wanted (with blue background).

Do you know any nice solution to make my goal fixed? Please take into consideration the responsive view.

```
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let event of events">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex mt-5">
            <!-- Card -->
            <div class="card shadow-light-lg lift lift-lg">
                <a class="card-body my-auto">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center align-items-center py-3">
                        <!-- some content -->
                        <h3 class="mt-auto">
                            {{event.title}}
                        </h3>

                        <div class="mb-0 text-muted" id="card-description">
                            {{event.description}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a snippet of yours problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width is not being applied properly. Either give width of 100%. Secondly you are using display-flex. So like parent has flex then items be given respective width.

Kindly share your code on stackblitz so we can better assist you. It will be much easier to debug.